# Bloomberg api Delphi "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" error

Tags: api, delphi, bloomberg

I am writing an app in Delphi 10.2 to retrieve price-data from Bloomberg for a risk valuation model that we are developing.

My steps were as follows :

1. I installed Bloomberg terminal on my development machine. (Downloaded sotrt10092018.exe from Bloomberg)

I then followed the following process in Delphi to install the TBlpdata Object

2. Component > Import component > Import ActiveX control > Next
3. Selected "Bloomberg data type library" > Next
4. Selected the "ActiveX" palette page
5. Selected a path where the unit will be placed
6. Selected "Generate component wrappers"  > Next
7. Selected "Create unit" > Finish
8. A unit was then created called BLP_DATA_CTRLLib_TLB.pas
9. I saved the unit and closed it.

I then started the process again :

10. Component > Install component >
11. Selected the BLP_DATA_CTRLLib_TLB file I created above
12. Selected "Install into a new package" > Next
13. Package name : BloombergAPI
14. Package description : Bloomberg API
15. Pressed Finish, and then I then received the following message "Unit BLP_DATA.. references the VCL Library but the project currently has no framework assigned, do you wish to enable the VCL framework for this project?' I replied Yes.
16. Saved my changes to project "BloombergAPI"
17. I then opened my FMX project, created a new VCL form (NOT FMX) and dropped the Bloomberg ActiveX BlpData component onto the form which is labelled Bloomberg ActiveX 4.3.1.
18. I have written the software to link to the data object, but my problem is as follows

When I run the app on my development machine the VCL form opens fine and all seems OK, but as soon as I run the app on the actual Bloomberg terminal I get the "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" error as it is trying to create the VCL form from within the FMX project.

Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is wise to try to mix VCL and FMX? You know that is not supported? Surely an ActiveX control doesn't sit well with using FMX. If you are going to use an ActiveX control then you are tied to Windows, at which point VCL is surely the better choice. Presumably you opt for FMX because you plan to support other platforms than Windows. In which case ActiveX is no good. Don't they have a REST API? ActiveX isn't very 2018.

Comment: Did you install/register the ActivX component on your "actual Bloomberg terminal"? You need those on every machine your application is running.

Comment: Hi David, may thanks for the reply. I was also concerned that mixing FMX and VCL would cause problems. However I have just created a small VCL app to test with and unfortunately am still receiving the error. I will find out from Bloomberg if they have a REST API offering.  Thanks again